# How to get the values of fields in c types structure with variable sized buffer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, struct, ctypes

```
import readboard
import struct
import ctypes as c

def readbuffer(data):
    size=  struct.unpack('<h', data[64:66])[0]
    class tabledata(c.Structure):
            _fields_ = [('delta', c.c_float),
                        ('x', c.c_float)]

    class tableparameters(c.Structure):
        _fields_ = [('parameter1', c.c_uint16*30),
                    ('parameter2', c.c_float),
                    ('size', c.c_uint16),
                    ('parameter3', c.c_uint16),
                    ('parameter4', c.c_float),
                    ('parameter5', c.c_float),
                    ('Table', tabledata*size)]
      
    return tableparameters

board = readboard.comport('COM1')
data = board.custommsg(readcommand, 256)
a = readbuffer(data)
print(a.parameter3)
print(a.parameter4)
print(a.Table)
print(a)
```

Output:

```
<Field type=c_ushort, ofs=66, size=2>
<Field type=c_float, ofs=68, size=4>
<Field type=tabledata, ofs=76, size=16>  
<class '__main__.readbuffer.<locals>.tableparameters'>
```

Output is the type, offset, and size, but I need to know the values. How can I get the values?

What I'm trying to do is define a structure with a variable sized buffer in which the field named 'size' has the value for the size of the field named 'Table'. I can't do it the same way it's done in c++, so I used struct.unpack to unpack size before the bytes are allocated in the fields. I don't really like this method. Is there another way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the `tableparameters` class was returned, not an instance of the class.  Create an instance from the raw data with `.from_buffer_copy()`.

Example with display routines:

```py
import struct
import ctypes as ct

# helper function
def read_buffer(data):
    size = struct.unpack('<h', data[64:66])[0] # extract size from byte data
    class TableData(ct.Structure):
        _fields_ = [('delta', ct.c_float),
                    ('x', ct.c_float)]
        def __repr__(self):
            return f'TableData(delta={self.delta}, x={self.x})'

    # Declare correctly-sized class inline
    class TableParameters(ct.Structure):
        _fields_ = [('parameter1', ct.c_uint16 * 30),
                    ('parameter2', ct.c_float),
                    ('size', ct.c_uint16),
                    ('parameter3', ct.c_uint16),
                    ('parameter4', ct.c_float),
                    ('parameter5', ct.c_float),
                    ('Table', TableData * size)]  # Use correct size here
        def __repr__(self):
            return f'''\
TableParameters(parameter1={list(self.parameter1)},
                parameter2={self.parameter2},
                size={self.size},
                parameter3={self.parameter3},
                parameter4={self.parameter4},
                parameter5={self.parameter5},
                Table={list(self.Table)})'''

    return TableParameters.from_buffer_copy(data)  # NOW use .from_buffer_copy()

data = struct.pack('<30HfHHff4f',*range(30),1.125,2,8,2.5,3.25,4.75,5.5,6.25,7.75)
print(read_buffer(data))
```

Output:

```
TableParameters(parameter1=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
                parameter2=1.125,
                size=2,
                parameter3=8,
                parameter4=2.5,
                parameter5=3.25,
                Table=[TableData(delta=4.75, x=5.5), TableData(delta=6.25, x=7.75)])
```

Comment: This really helped. How would you go about resizing it? Let's say I want to add more points to 'Table' before sending it back. Changing the 'size' value only changed the value for the 'size' field but not the 'size' variable that is unpacked

Comment: @IsaacZaiek I was playing around with that idea after posting this answer. Create a new question and I’ll answer it.

Comment: just created a new question.